# Why does Boolean.getBoolean never seem to return true

Tags: java

Based upon the java doc I have no logical explanation for this. Any ideas?

```
Boolean.getBoolean(Boolean.TRUE.toString()) == false
```

See it for yourself:
https://ideone.com/rKa2dS

Nothing clear to me why in the Java Doc
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#getBoolean-java.lang.String-

Comment: How about reading the documentation that you posted yourself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It *is* there in the docs you linked:

> Returns true if and only if **the system property** named by the argument exists and is equal to the string "true".

Note the emphasis. So `Boolean.getBoolean("foo")` returns `true` if there is a system property named `foo` with the value `"true"`, and `false` if there isn't one or it has another value.

If you want the boolean value of a string, use [`Boolean.parseBoolean(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean-java.lang.String-) (if you want a `boolean`) or [`Boolean.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) (if you want a `Boolean`).